# node.js - parameterized routes with Express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

Things are sort of working but, for some reason, I can't get the user_id into the URL, all I get is a literal ":user_id" like so:

[image]

here is the code in the my users.js route file

```
var main = require('../main');

exports.getAllUsers = function(req, res) {

    var db = main.db();

    db.collection('users').find().toArray(function(err, items) {
        res.json(items);
    });

};

exports.routeUserToTheirHome = function(req, res, next) {
      res.json(req.user);
};
```

and here is the code in my main.js file:

```
app.param('user_id', function(req, res, next, user_id) {
    // typically we might sanity check that user_id is of the right format
    User.find(user_id, function(err, user) {
        if (err) {
            return next(err);
        }
        if (!user) {
            return new Error("no user matched");
        }
        req.user = user;
        next();
    });
});

app.use('/users/:user_id/home', users.routeUserToTheirHome);
```

Comment: node.js is not an application framework, and has no concept of routes. Please tag correctly with the framework you are using (e.g. Sails.js, Total.js, Locomotive.js...)

Comment: whoops forgot to include the expressJS tag ;)

Comment: I don't get it though - did you enter that URL? Was it a link? And how did it find henry if `user_id` was `:user_id`? That screenshot makes no sense to me... Can you explain what happens if you surf to http://localhost:3000/users/5464370621a2569c18880876/home ? Does it find henry again? What exact problem are you facing?

Comment: Thanks @Armadan, I believe I am missing some information about how this works, need to do more reading then get back to you

Comment: @Armadan, see my answer below and see if it makes sense to you, thank you

Comment: Two basic recommendations: a) use the Custom Callback mechanism of [`authenticate`](http://passportjs.org/guide/authenticate/), or b) redirect to `/home`, and in that route display the same content as in `/users/.../home` for the current user. (You could also redirect from `/home` to `/users/.../home`, but that is less pretty.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what the problem was, it was that I had this:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect : 'users/:user_id/home',
    failureRedirect : '/login',
    failureFlash : true
}), function(req, res, next) {
    next();
});
```

when in fact, I needed this:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect : 'users/' + '5464370621a2569c18880876' +'/home',
    failureRedirect : '/login',
    failureFlash : true
}), function(req, res, next) {
    next();
});
```

clearly I don't know what I am doing. The question now is, where do I get the user_id from, instead of hardcoding it?

here is the solution:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    failureRedirect : '/login',
    failureFlash : true
}), function(req, res, next) {
    res.redirect('users/' + req.user._id +'/home');
    next();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
exports.routeUserToTheirHome = function(req, res, next) {
    req.user.user_id = req.params.user_id;
    res.json(req.user);
};
```

Comment: user_id is undefined here for me, not sure what the problem is